# I've written a code for reverse a string. But in output it is generating some garbage. Why?

Tags: c, string, reverse

Here is my code. For word with more than 3 alphabets in o/p garbage values are generated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char a[50],b[50];
    gets(a);
    puts(a);
    int len,i,j;
    i=0;
    while(a[i]!='\0'){
       i++;
    }
    printf("Length: %d",i);
    //reverse
    len = i;
    j=len-1;
    for(i=0;i<=len-1;i++){
        printf("\ni=%d j=%d",i,j);
        b[i]=a[j];
        j--;

    }
    printf("\n___REVERSED TEXT___\n");
    puts(b);


}
```

Comment: Don’t use `gets()` ever; it cannot be used safely.

Comment: Did you null terminate the reversed string?  I think not.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you know that `i<=len-1` is the same as `i<len`, right? Same meaning, easier to read, and less to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters neither declaration from the header `<stdlib.h>` is used in the program. So this directive

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

may be removed.

According to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `gets`  is unsafe and is not supported any more by the C Standard. Instead use function `fgets`.

When the string stored in the array `a` is being copied in the array `b` the terminating zero also should be copied to the end of the resulted string.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   50

int main( void ) 
{
    char a[N], b[N];

    fgets( a, sizeof( a ), stdin );

    size_t length = 0;

    while ( a[length] != '\0' && a[length] != '\n' ) ++length;

    a[length] = '\0';

    puts( a );

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) b[i] = a[length - i - 1];
    b[i] = '\0';

    printf("\n___REVERSED TEXT___\n");
    puts( b );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Hello, World!
Hello, World!

___REVERSED TEXT___
!dlroW ,olleH
```

Comment: why not `(for i = 0, j = length; i < j; i++, j--)` and swap 2 per iteration?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin According to the code presented in the question he is trying to copy and reverse a string instead of reversing "in place".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char a[50],b[50];

    printf("\nWhat is the word?");
    scanf("%s", a); fflush(stdin);
    int j;

    printf("Length: %lu",strlen(a));
    for(j = strlen(a) - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        b[strlen(a) - 1 - j] = a[j];
    }
    printf("\n___REVERSED TEXT___\n");
    printf("\n%s", b);
}
```

- use function strlen of string.h to get the size of the string;
- the for goes from the end to the beginning of string a filling the string b